# How to use two database reference in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase cloud Functions to Trigger Notifications and Can we use onWrite() on two database references. If possible how to accomplish?

Comment: One function can only respond to changes at one location at a time.

Comment: I'm just using a single database for both Admin and Client app and I need to trigger notifications to both apps when two specific nodes are updated with data. Is this possible? @DougStevenson

Comment: Sure, write two different functions for the two nodes that do similar work to send the messages.

Comment: Sure, I'll work on it! @DougStevenson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features and HTTPS requests but a single cloud function can only respond to changes that happens also at a single location at a time.

If you have more that one node that you want to be triggered, you need to write separate (different) functions for each node that can work similarly.